# How do I change the sql query for wp_get_archive()

Tags: categories, archive-template

I am using `wp_get_archive()` in `category.php`.

If I am on page of `category=2` it should show my archives of only that category. However it is for all the categories.

So how can I change the query for `wp_get_archive()` that it only redirects to archive template for that specific category
this is the code in my `category.php`

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
 <?php 
   $args =array(               
                'posts_per_page' =>1,                 
           );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );                                            
  if($loop->have_posts()):while ( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();
   the_content();
  endwhile;
  endif;
 ?>
 <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'daily') ); ?>
```

and if the same code for `archive.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1291) for [`wp_get_archives()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives), there is a filter called  [`getarchives_join`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1384) which you can use to restrict `wp_get_archives()` to a specific category

You also need to get the current category ID, which is easy, simply use `get_queried_object_id()`

You can try something like this to display archives for the currently viewed category

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_join', function ($r) 
{

    global $wpdb;

    if( is_category() ) {
        $category_id = get_queried_object_id();
        $r =  $wpdb->prepare( " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr ON $wpdb->posts.ID = tr.object_id  AND tr.term_taxonomy_id IN (%s)", $category_id );
    }
    return $r;

}, 10, 2 );
```

### EDIT

Just one or two comments about your code in your last edit. As that is the code in category.php and archive.php templates, you should not make use of custom queries. I suspect that this is where you big problem is.

Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query to suit your needs. You have to remove the custom queries and go back to the default loop in those two archive pages.

This is how your category page should look like

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 
if( have_posts() ) {

    while ( have_posts() ) { 
        the_post();

        the_content();

    }

}
?>

<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'daily') ); ?>
```

Then, in your functions.php, addd the following code

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) 
{

    if(    !is_admin() 
        && $q->is_main_query() 
        && (    $q->is_category() 
             || $q->is_date() 
            ) 
    ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
    }
});
```

This will set the posts per page to one on the archive and category pages

Comment: I tried it but the result is same                                                 Thanks                                                                      I think if when i clicking on Jan 2,2014 and i am on page of cat=3   then According to the new query(given by you)  the url should be like ?/m=20150101&cat=3    but i still get ?/m=2015010 only                                                   Isn't it

Comment: Works on my side. What are you trying to achieve. The code only returns archive for the current category

Comment: I have edited my question to include my code..Please see

Comment: worked perfectly i was doing the mistake of using category.php  although just archive.php was needeed.

Comment: thanks for helping so much                           Now you really understand me what i want to do.So going to start new question                                         Actually the code above didn't work but i thought it did.Mistake on my part.

Comment: This code **does** work. If you are on the category page, it displays only archives for the specific category. The problem is, if you go to that specific archive, it shows all posts from that archive, not just from the specific category. This is another issue, not an issue with my code

Comment: I have, for reference, added an example of how your archive and category page should look like. Please see the **EDIT** section

Comment: thanks @Pieter Goosen learned a lot from you while solving this problem

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)